# AngularJS delete default empty option in directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have this directive that brings sub-categories by the categoryId in this application the categories are called services and the sub-categories are called services-child( just for you to know ).

ok
The File that contain the directive service-detail.php has:

```
<services-child serviceid="{{id}}"></services-child>
```

The directive :

```
'use strict';
app.directive('servicesChild', function ($window,$state,servChildService) {
return {
    require: '^form',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      serviceid: '@',
    },
    templateUrl:'assets/views/partials/service-child.php',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        var serviceId = $attributes.serviceid;

        $scope.childs = servChildService;
        servChildService.loadServiceChilds(serviceId);
        $scope.serviceChilds = servChildService.serviceCH;

    }
};
});


app.factory('serviceChildResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource("/services/serviceChild/:id", {id: '@id'}, {
    getChilds: {
        method: 'GET'
    }
});
}]);

app.service('servChildService', function(serviceChildResource) {

 var self = {
    'isLoading': false,
    'showBlock': true,
    'serviceCH': [],
    'loadServiceChilds': function(serviceId){

        if (!self.isLoading) {

            self.isLoading = true;
            var params = {
                'id': serviceId,
            };

            self.serviceCH = [];
            serviceChildResource.getChilds(params, function(data){

                if(data.childs.length > 0){
                    angular.forEach(data.childs, function(value, key){
                        self.serviceCH.push(new serviceChildResource(value));
                        self.isLoading = false;
                        self.showBlock = true;
                    });
                }else{
                    self.showBlock = false; 
                    self.isLoading = false; //show the loading.
                }

            });




        }

    }

 };

 return self;
 });
```

Now the services-child view is this service-child.php:

```
<div class="panel panel-white" ng-show="childs.showBlock">
<div class="panel-heading border-light">
    <h4 class="panel-title"><span class="text-bold">Add More Services</span> 
    </h4>
</div>

<div class="table-responsive">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="sample-table-1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Service</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Qty.</th>
                    <th>Select</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="service in serviceChilds">
                    <td>{{service.name}}</td>
                    <td ng-bind-html="service.description"> 
                        {{service.description}}
                    </td>
                    <td>${{service.price}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <qty-select ng-hide="{{service.single_service}}" 
                                    price="{{service.price}}"
                                    id="{{service.id}}"
                                    indexid = {{$index}}>
                        </qty-select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{service.id}}" 
                        ng-model="$root.servCheck[service.id]" 
                                name="servCheckN"/></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    <div ng-show="childs.isLoading">
        <span us-spinner="{radius:10, width:5, length:4, lines:8}"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ok Now in this directive I have another Directive that has the Dynamic DropDown:
as you see this is the directive:

```
<qty-select ng-hide="{{service.single_service}}" 
     price="{{service.price}}"
     id="{{service.id}}"
     indexid = {{$index}}>
</qty-select>
```

Now this directive code is this qty-select.js:

```
'use strict';
app.directive('qtySelect', function ($window,$state,servChildService,$localStorage,$rootScope,$timeout) {
return {
    require: '^form',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      indexid: '@',
    },
    templateUrl:'assets/views/partials/qty-select.php',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        var i = 1;

        while (i < 16) {
            $scope.selectObj.push({'value' : $attributes.price * i,  
                   'label' : i + ' (' + $attributes.price * i + ')', 
                   'price' : $attributes.price * i,
                   'qty'   : i,
            });
            i += 1;
        };


        console.log($rootScope.priceQty);

    }
};
});
```

So basically what this directive does is creating a select option element 
but it shows the price multiply by the index Ex. 1($10) which increment one by one
Ex. 2($20) so the result is something like this: if you pass 10 to the directive in the price attribute it will show:

```
<select ng-init="$parent.priceQty[indexid] = selectObj[0]" 
 ng-model="$parent.priceQty[indexid]" ng-change="updatePrice()" 
 ng-options="option.label for option in selectObj" 
 class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style="">
<option value="?"></option>
<option label="1 (15)" value="object:77">1 (15)</option>
<option label="2 (30)" value="object:78">2 (30)</option>
<option label="3 (45)" value="object:79">3 (45)</option>
<option label="4 (60)" value="object:80">4 (60)</option>
<option label="5 (75)" value="object:81">5 (75)</option>
<option label="6 (90)" value="object:82">6 (90)</option>
<option label="7 (105)" value="object:83">7 (105)</option>
<option label="8 (120)" value="object:84">8 (120)</option>
<option label="9 (135)" value="object:85">9 (135)</option>
</select>
```

Now this all works fine but I don't know how to get ride of the first empty option that angular append to the dropDown.

This is the View directive for select qty-select.php

```
<select ng-init="$root.priceQty[indexid] = selectObj[0]" 
    ng-model="$root.priceQty[indexid]" ng-change="updatePrice()" 
    ng-options="option.label for option in selectObj" >
</select>

<!-- <select ng-model="$root.priceQty[indexid]" ng-change="updatePrice(indexid)">
<option ng-repeat="value in selectObj" value="{{value.value}}" 
        ng-selected="$index == 1">{{value.label}}</option>
</select> -->
```

As you see in the I am trying with ng-repeat and with ng-options but 
i am having problems with both.

Now if I work with $scope it works but when I am trying to use root 
it does not work.

I notice that in my view select i have set

```
<select ng-init="$root.priceQty[indexid] = selectObj[0]"
```

but in the html that gets populated I see

```
<select ng-init="$parent.priceQty[indexid] = selectObj[0]"
```

$parent why ? is changing it.

and I need to set these input in the rootScope because I have to submit the form and I can no access to those values if I don't set the ng-model to be sent to the rootScope.

Also I tried to do this in the qty-select.js directive

after I build the select element i added this:

```
$scope.priceQty = $scope.selectObj[0];
```

and it worked but when I use $rooScope it doesn't work it says undefined.

```
$rootScope.priceQty = $scope.selectObj[0];
```

Any Idea?

Thank you

Comment: you seem to have two separate questions here;  to the second half, **never** use `$rootScope` like this, it defeats the purpose of creating a usable directive entirely.  Instead, add a property to the `scope` property for the directive to use to store the selected item;  If the element using the directive passes a value, then use that as a default in the directive, and update the property as necessary in the directive.

Comment: the more I read this, the less it makes sense.  it would be helpful if you created a reproducible example of the directive.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thank you very much for your feedback...
Im not using `$rootScope` and a fixed the problem with the empty.
I had a lot architectural mistakes and thank you for your recommendations.
I totally change the way of using the directive.

Ok the way I solved the empty option was

```
'use strict';
app.directive('qtySelect', function ($window,$state,servChildService,$timeout,cartService,$cookies,$rootScope) {
return {
    require: '^form',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      indexid: '@',
      serviId: '@id',
      servobj: '=',
    },
    templateUrl:'assets/views/partials/qty-select.php',
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        var i = 1;
        var index = 0;
        $scope.selectObj = [];
        $scope.cartArray = [];

        while (i < 16) {

            $scope.selectObj.push({'value' : $attributes.price * i, //the value of the option tag (obligatory) 
                                   'label' : i + ' (' + $attributes.price * i + ')', //the copy (obligatory) 
                                   'price' : $attributes.price * i,
                                   'qty'   : i,
                                   'serviceId' : $attributes.id,
                                   'index' : index,
                                });


            i += 1;
            index += 1;

        };

        $timeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("qty-"+$scope.indexid)[1].selected = true

            //add the attribute ng-checked to filter them later.
            document.getElementById("qty-"+$scope.indexid)[1].setAttribute("selected", 'selected');
        }, 10);






    }
};
});
```

I'm targeting the element by id and I am adding timeout because
the first load return undefined it seems the DOM is not ready 
at that point so adding a timeout it give it enough time to the DOM to be ready.
Also I am adding the attribute selected="selected" manually since the selected true does not add the attribute selected and I need it to select later the whole element.

```
$timeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("qty-"+$scope.indexid)[1].selected = true

            //addinf manyally the attribute selected
            document.getElementById("qty-"+$scope.indexid)[1].setAttribute("selected", 'selected');
}, 10);
```

Thank you 
If you have recommendations are welcome.

This is the html directive:

```
<select ng-model="priceQty" ng-change="updatePrice(indexid,serviId,this)" 
    name="priceQty" id="qty-{{indexid}}">

    <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in selectObj" value="{{value.price}}" 
            qty="{{$index+1}}" service-id="{{serviId}}">
        {{$index+1}} ({{value.price}}) 
    </option>

</select>
```